# Xamarin.iOS Notification Suggestion

Tags: push-notification, notifications, xamarin.ios

Need to show notification in Xamarin.iOS app. 
Calling web service at some interval when
application in background 
Any better approach ?

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: I think you should search on Xamarin documentation instead asking here ,https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/user-notifications/deprecated/remote_notifications_in_ios/

Comment: Thanks Cole for a reply.
I read document regarding that which says there are types 1. Local notification 2. Remote notification <br/>
Just want to how could my service would call my mobile application to notify ? Shall I make any changes in web api for that ?
Actly i need a example ?

Answer (score 1):

For this, you can use local notification. You can use below code where you are calling web service:

// create the notification

```
var notification = new UILocalNotification();

// set the fire date (the date time in which it will fire)
notification.FireDate = NSDate.FromTimeIntervalSinceNow(60);

// configure the alert
notification.AlertAction = "View Alert";
notification.AlertBody = "Your one minute alert has fired!";

// modify the badge
notification.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

// set the sound to be the default sound
notification.SoundName = UILocalNotification.DefaultSoundName;

// schedule it
UIApplication.SharedApplication.ScheduleLocalNotification(notification);
```